# ASP.NET Identity with Sustainsys Saml2 - How to persist ExternalLoginInfo Claims?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3, sustainsys-saml2

I have an ASP.NET Core app, targeting netcoreapp3.1, set up with ASP.NET Identity and the Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2 package.

IDP-initiated SAML authentication is working fine, but I can't retrieve custom attributes/claims from the signed-in user after the authentication redirect.

In my `ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs` class, the custom claims are present on the `ExternalLoginInfo.Principal` (as `var info` in the code below), but they are not retrievable from `Context.User.Claims` after the redirect.

That is, `_logger.LogInformation($"PatientId: {info.Principal.FindFirst("PatientId")}");` prints the value passed in the custom `PatientId` SAML attribute, but `@Context.User.FindFirst("PatientId");` is null after the redirect.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetCallbackAsync(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            if (remoteError != null)
            {
                ErrorMessage = $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}";
                return RedirectToPage("./Login", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            }
            var info = await _CustomSignInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Error loading external login information.";
                return RedirectToPage("./Login", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            }

            // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
            var result = await _CustomSignInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"{info.Principal.Identity.Name} logged in with {info.LoginProvider} provider.");
                _logger.LogInformation($"PatientId: {info.Principal.FindFirst("PatientId")}");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }

    ...
}
```

My conclusion from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51925027/11870335) is that these claims should still be available. Do I need to somehow  pass the `ExternalLoginInfo.Principal` (rather just the `LoginProvider` and `ProviderKey`) to the `ExternalLoginSignInAsync` method?

I will say that I only want to persist the claims for the length of the session, not add them as `AspNetUserClaims` the database. They will be different on each login.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out something that works. My question at the end there, "*Do I need to somehow pass the ExternalLoginInfo.Principal (rather just the LoginProvider and ProviderKey) to the ExternalLoginSignInAsync method?*" was on the right track.

As you can see above, the `ExternalLoginSignInAsync` method is in the `CustomSignInManager` class (it's a custom implementation for reasons not relevant to this question, but that method was unchanged from the default ASP.NET Identity [SignInManager](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/2c9e1940204837bcd425e8f4488bf2564434b357/src/Identity/SignInManager.cs)).

Tracing the request path to the "bottom," `ExternalLoginSignInAsync` calls `SignInOrTwoFactorAsync`, which calls `SignInAsync`. In `SignInAsync`, a new `ClaimsIdentity` is created and returned. So I simply had to pass them from the `ExternalLoginInfo.Principal` instance through all of those methods such that I could set them on the new principal.

Potentially helpful minutiae: I chose to create a `CustomClaimSet` class to store the custom attributes, and then I had to update all the method signatures to accept a `CustomClaimSet` as an argument.